# Linguistic Formula

Tags: formatting, linguistics

I am trying to type linguistic formulas in LateX.
An example would be smilar to this:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/AmerEngFlappingRule_annotated.PNG

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange! The [`phonrule` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/phonrule?lang=en) is designed to support phonological rule notation of this kind. Why don't you try using that, and then update your question with a Minimal Working Example if you are having trouble making it work.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't clear whether the red digits are part of the desired answer or mere annotations.  If required, please comment me to this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[\Centerstack{+ stop\\+ consonant\\+ alveolar}\right]
  \rightarrow [\mathbf{r}]
    \scalerel{/}{\Centerstack{\\\\}}
  \left[\Centerstack{+ vowel\\+ stressed}\right]
  \Centerstack{\\\\\makebox[2em]{\hrulefill}}
  \left[\Centerstack{+ vowel\\$-$ stressed}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

All in bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,scalerel}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\TABstackTextstyle{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[\tabbedCenterstack{+ stop\\+ consonant\\+ alveolar}\right]
  \rightarrow [\tabbedCenterstack{r}]
    \scalerel{/}{\Centerstack{\\\\}}
  \left[\tabbedCenterstack{+ vowel\\+ stressed}\right]
  \Centerstack{\\\\\makebox[2em]{\hrulefill}}
  \left[\tabbedCenterstack{+ vowel\\$-$ stressed}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you that is beautiful!